# Copying Concatenate Formula With Static A Column & 1 Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a pseudo table in Excel that concatenates a static header row and static header column.

The problem is when I copy (drag) the formula across the table, Excel isn't recognizing that I'm looking to pull the data from the static row/column.

I've tried manually entering the formula across 2 adjacent cells hoping that Excel would pick up on the pattern, but it's not.

Is there a mystery function (or way to manipulate Concatenate or &) to get the desired effect?  Tried to outline in image below and realize I interchanged row/column when pointing out the formula =/.  Actual data is a much larger table.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$` to mark an Absolute Reference:

```
=$A3&" "&B$2
```

[image]